# How to scan and message devices connected to OpenThread border router from Android app?

Tags: android, mobile, embedded, ip, protocols

I have set up a Smart Home device with an OpenThread Border Router and a Thread-capable test device (light). Now I would like to scan from an Android device which devices with which IPs are connected to the OpenThread Border Router and then send messages to it. I can modify both the test device and the Android app as I like. However, I cannot make any changes to the OpenThread Border Router, as it is intended to be replaced later by any Thread Border Router (such as Alexa). I have also seen that the functions I need are available in the OpenThread library, but unfortunately, I do not know how to access them from my Android app.